# Given $3$-dimensional subspaces $V, W \subset \Bbb R^5$, there is a nonzero vector in $V \cap W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove that if $V$ and $W$ are three-dimensional subspaces of $\Bbb R^{5}$, then $V$ and $W$ must have a non-zero vector in common.

So far I got $V = \{v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}\}$ and $W = \{ w_{1}, w_{2}, w_{3}\}$ because they are 3-dimensional subspaces. Then $V \cup W = \{v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}, w_{1}, w_{2}, w_{3}\}$

My prof said that now I need to prove that they are linearly independent so this is a contradiction and the statement is wrong because we are in $\Bbb R^{5}$ and we have 6 elements on it.

I don't know how to express them as a linearly independent proof, so I hope anyone can give me a good explanation on it.

Comment: You mean $V \cup W = \{ v_1, v_2, v_3, w_1, w_2, w_3 \}$?

Comment: yes, sorry for mistakes

Comment: Do you understand this more general statement: if you have $n$ dimensions, then you can have at most $n$ linearly independent vectors? So for instance the vectors $(251,12), (-43,\pi), (95918,0.0001)$ can not be linearly independent (I chose numbers at random to illustrate the strength of this statement).

Comment: I think the above hint should be:
$$ \dim (V + W) = \dim (V) + \dim (W) - \dim (V \cap W) $$

Comment: Had to post as answer because I can't comment yet (not enough rep?).

Comment: Yes, the union of subspaces is not a subspace, in general, so it can't have a dimension.

Answer (score 4):

Let {v1,v2,v3} - any basis of V;

Let {w1,w2,w3} - any basis of W;

vectors {v1,v2,v3,w1,w2,w3} are linearly dependent, because 6 vectors are too much for R5.

So that, there exist linear combination

c1*v1+c2*v2+c3*v3+d1*w1+d2*w2+d3*w3=0

such that coefficients c1,c2,c3,d1,d2,d3 are NOT ALL zeros.

Thus, common vector:

t = c1*v1+c2*v2+c3*v3 = -d1*w1-d2*w2-d3*w3

in {v1,v2,v3} and {w1,w2,w3} basis respectively.

t is zero-vector iff c1,c2,c3,d1,d2,d3 are ALL zeros.

But prevoiusly showed that they are NOT ALL zero, so t is not zero-vector.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:
$$ \dim (V + W) = \dim (V) + \dim (W) - \dim (V \cap W) $$

Answer (score 1):

We know that if $V$ and $W$ are subspaces, then $V\cap W$ and $V+W$ are also subspaces. Recall $V+W$ is the smallest subspace which contains both $V$ and $W$. So, $\dim(V+W)$ is 3 or 4 or 5.

We know that $\dim(\mathbb{R}^5) \geq \dim(V+ W) = \dim(V)+\dim(W)-\dim(V\cap W)$ which implies that $5 \geq \dim(V+ W) = 3+3-\dim(V\cap W)$.

Hence, to satisfy above equation, $\dim(V\cap W)$ is at least 1. Thus, any basis of  $V\cap W$ contains at least one non-zero vector, i.e., $V\cap W=\text{span}(S)$, where $|S|\geq 1$, $S$ being basis. Take any vector in $S$ or non-zero vector in $\text{span}(S)$ vector.